# Is experience a real thing?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, reality, experience

Reality is both  objective and subjective or neither , But what about experience ? 
since experience is totally subjective does this mean it may or may not be real? 
for example, You hear a person saying that the way to be rich is to do that and that , but you can be rich using another path (that's obvious somehow), does it mean that experience isn't real ?because in this example its not objective!
reality is subjective and objective or neither and since the previous example shows that experience is only subjective this means that its not real according to the definition !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me 'objectivity' begs the question, *who's* objectivity? How can we gain evidence of it? Only through subjectivities. See:

[Does there exist truly objective thoughts?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/82262/does-there-exist-truly-objective-thoughts/82289#82289)

What we call objectivity, is really intersubjectivity - others inviting us into their experiences & them in to ours, then using mental tools developed communally & over time, to reason about them.

There is no totally subjective, because we use communally developed language to engage with our experiences (eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue%E2%80%93green_distinction_in_language - not just a matter of relabelling, but actually affecting the salience landscape involved in identifying colours).

There is no totally objective, because that implicitly requires a 'mind of god' perspective to be arbiter of what counts.

Intersubjectivity is exactly about experiences, but approached as 'what if someone else was here seeing this', and thinking through questions they might ask etc. That's how scientists make observations also, using tools & methods, *within* their experiences.

If someone is telling you how to get rich, chances are they got rich from suckers buying their advice. If their way to get rich worked, surely they would be using it, not selling it. The real money in the goldrush, was made selling spades - the origins of Walmart. A lot more money has been made selling trees inoculated with perigord truffled, than from perigord truffles the trees produced.